# addressing an unsigned 16bit vector with an unsigned 32bit offset vector

Tags: arm, neon, intrinsics

I have a pointer to an unsigned 16 bit vector `uint16x8_t *_h;`
I need to add some calculated unsigned 32 bit **vector offset** to this pointer - the offset looks like this: `uint32x4_t _o32x4;`
the question is how to do that using **neon intrinsics**?

thanks

**EDIT**

Let say that I have the following:

```
uint16_t * h = malloc(N * sizeof(uint16_t));
uint16x8_t * _p = (uint16x8_t *) h;
```

where `N` is a multiple of `8`. `_p` points to a vector of `8` `uint16_t` values. Now, if I do `_p + offset` where offset is a **'constant'** `integer`, I will access the data pointed by h at the position `8 x offset`.

Now let say that offset **is not a 'constant'** but is a **vector** of 4 values
as so  `uint32x4_t offset;` I'm interested to offset `_p` with this offset.The question is: **is it possible?** and if it's possible, **how to do it?**

Comment: A pointer is a scalar value. What do you mean you want to add a vector offset to a scalar value? It's not entirely clear what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: @Isogen74 - see my **EDIT** above.

Comment: What do you expect your resulting type to be?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible?

No - what you are proposing isn't valid in C.

Comment: you're wrong. I'm doing the stuff in the **EDIT** all the time.

Comment: Pretty sure you are not doing `pointer + vector` as it wouldn't compile.
You may get away with `pointer + sizeof(vector)`, but the type pointed to by your pointer and the type of vector are not the same, which is type aliasing and therefore not allowed in recent standards.